# laravel5.1 Manually Authenticating Users

Tags: php, authentication, laravel-5.1

In my app I use the default authentification to login my users to their dashboard.
Now I would like to create a backend for supporters and one for admins.
I use this code at the moment to login as admin:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App;
use Artisan;
use Validator;
use Auth;

class AdminLoginController extends Controller
{

    public function index()
    {
        return view('admin.login');

    }

    public function authenticate(Request $request)
    {
         if (Auth::attempt(['username' => $request->username, 'password' => $request->password, 'id' => 1])) 
        {
            // Authentication passed...
            dd("correct");
        }
        else
        {
            dd("login data incorrect!");

        }
    }

}
```

How can I use now the well known redirects after login.
In my AuthController I use for the users I use this code:

```
/**
 * Where to redirect users after login / registration.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $redirectTo = '/dashboard';
protected $redirectAfterLogout = 'auth/login';
protected $redirectPath = '/dashboard';
```

1.) How can I use this in my code above? I would like to redirect admins logged into the app like users to specified urls using this laravel feature.

2.) What's the best way, to check more "ids" in the if statement? Because there will be more than one admin.

Comment: please explain, are you able to successfully match the user information? 2nd, why don't you use role based packages for laravel eg: `https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust` 3rd instead of passing `id`  place `user_type` field in user table. and check for that while login

Answer (score 1):

first of all you are checking username, password along with a ID. So only user with Id = 1 is going to be authenticated by your function. You dont need to put an id check there.

Now for the redirect you can make a function which returns back the url based on the user type. Here is a very basic example`

```
public function getRedirectUrl(){
    if(auth()->user()->isAdmin()){
        return url('/admin-dashboard');
    }
   elseif(auth()->user()->isUser()){
     return url('/user-dashboard')
     }
}
```

Make sure you have isAdmin() and isUser() function defined in your User model like

```
public function isAdmin(){
  return $this->user_type == UserType::ADMIN;
}
```

So in your authentication function just do `return redirect($this->getRedirectUrl())`

Comment: Thanks a lot, but how to do a check in the isAdmin() function, to check, if the user id matches an array of ids? Using the ids to check for admin privileges is a better solution for me.

Comment: Think ahead, say your application now has 10000s of users. How will you keep track of the id for admin, for client ???
You need to group your users based on another column. Say user_type_id. then give all your admins the value of 10, users value of 1. Then in isAdmin() you can simply check if $this->user_type_id == 10;